# replace pandas по спискам

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Нужно в pandas сделать списочную замену слов.
Есть код:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('replace_origin.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df_lib = pd.read_excel('replace_lib.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df_1 = '|'.join(df_lib['old'])
df_2 = '|'.join(df_lib['new'])
print(df_1)
print(df_2)
df['test'] = df['test'].str.replace(df_1, df_2,regex=True)
df.to_excel('replace_test.xlsx')
```

но проблема в том, что на замену передается весть столбец из переменной `df_2`, пример:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': ['Иванов Иван Иванович', 'Петров С.А.', 'Алексеев Евгений', 'Сидоров Георгий Иванович']})
df_lib = pd.DataFrame({'old': ['Иванов', 'Петров', 'Сидоров'],'new': ['Ivanov', 'Petrov', 'Sidorov']})
```

На выходе мы получаем следующее:

```
Ivanov|Petrov|Sidorov Иван Ivanov|Petrov|Sidorovич
Ivanov|Petrov|Sidorov С.А.
Алексеев Евгений
```

Что я делаю не так? Однозначно, что-то нужно мудрить с `df_2`, но что конкретно?

Comment: вы приведите пример исходных данных и что на что вы хотите заменить. так - мало понятно.

Comment: @strawdog Я так понял, автор хочет, чтобы по отдельным словам словарная замена сработала.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно заменить подстроку, то можете сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': ['Иванов Иван Иванович', 'Петров С.А.', 'Алексеев Евгений', 'Сидоров Георгий Иванович']})
df_lib = pd.DataFrame({'old': ['Иванов', 'Петров', 'Сидоров'],'new': ['Ivanov', 'Petrov', 'Sidorov']})
repl_doct = dict(zip(df_lib["old"], df_lib["new"]))
df = df.replace({"test":repl_doct}, regex=True)
```

Только обратите внимание на отчества.
df:

```
                       test
0      Ivanov Иван Ivanovич
1               Petrov С.А.
2          Алексеев Евгений
3  Sidorov Георгий Ivanovич
```

чтобы избежать конфуза с отчествами, можно выделить фамилии с пробелом на конце для замены, то есть, в словаре замены сделать просто:

```
repl_doct = dict(zip(df_lib["old"]+ " ", df_lib["new"]+" "))
```

тогда получите годный датафрейм:

```
                       test
0      Ivanov Иван Иванович
1               Petrov С.А.
2          Алексеев Евгений
3  Sidorov Георгий Иванович
```

Comment: strawdog Гениально! Спасибо!